# Bootstrap: .nav-stacked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm developing an application and I'm using Bootstrap v3.3.5. I have  created a navigation but I would like to have two different views.

The first one should be for tablets and computer with icons and the name of this menu item. This shouldn't be a dropdown menu.

The second one should be for phones with icons and a dropdown-menu-right. How can I make this responsive sidebar?

Thanks in advance..

[Bootstrap .nav-stacked picture](https://www.dropbox.com/s/l8lig9ksk9zx6nc/Menu.png?dl=0)

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<head>
 <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
</head>


<body>
  <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked" id="pills-first">
   <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-glass"></span>  Glas</a></li>

   <li><a href="#" data-target="#submenu1"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-music"></span> Music</a></li>
   <ul id="submenu1">
    <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-volume-off"></span> Volume off</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-volume-down"></span> Volume down</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-volume-up"></span> Volume up</a></li>
   </ul>
       
  
   <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span> Search</a></li>
  </ul>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: 'dropdown-menu-right' doesn't display the dropdown menu to the right of the button/item. They still display below, but they are right aligned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are able to create the desired result using a combination of media-queries and visible/hidden classes.

I had to create two versions of the Music link, one to work as the dropdown toggle for mobile and the other as a regular link for tablet/desktop. I used "hidden-xs" and "visible-xs" to show/hide the correct one for that defined mobile view.

To update the dropdown nav to appear to the side for mobile i used this css using media queries:

```
@media(max-width:767px) {
    li a[data-target="#submenu1"], #submenu1 {
        float:left;
    }
    #submenu1 {
        padding-left: 0;
        margin-left: -5px;
        list-style: none
    }
    #submenu1>li {
        display: inline-block;
        padding-right: 5px;
        padding-left: 5px
    }
    .dropdown {
        display:inline-block;
    }
    #submenu1 {
        left:100%;
        top:0;
        width:250px;
        border:0;
        box-shadow:none;
        margin:0;
    }
}
```

And so the music dropdown was always visible for tablet/desktop i used this css:

```
@media(min-width:7678px) {
    .dropdown-menu {
        position:relative;
        display:block;
        float:none;
    }
}
```

It still requires some styling but you can see an example of the result you are looking for here:
https://jsfiddle.net/partypete25/8Lrr88y5/